# SSL certificate is untrusted still works in iOS app

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, ssl, mobile

SSL certificate chain issue is "incomplete" means we have an invalid or missing intermediate (bundle) certificate. In Android app, It shows proper error "Untrusted SSL" and app never works.
But in iOS app, it's not providing any SSL error and app works.
Just want to know if intermediate certificate is invalid or missing still iOS app works? what all the valid parameters/attributes required for valid SSL in iOS app?